# Jetpack compose - How to set multiple animation spec in animation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**My problem:**

I need to set image transition animation for some duration. I want to give some spring effects using spring()

```
   spring (stiffness = Spring. StiffnessLow)
```

But the problem is Jetpack compose animation spec allows one spec at a time. **I can able to set either tween() or spring(). But I want both spec in same animation**

**My code:**

```
@Composable
private fun TransitionAnimation() {
    var isAnimated by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = isAnimated, label = "")

    val rocketOffset by transition.animateOffset(transitionSpec = {
        if (this.targetState) {
            tween(1000)
        } else {
            tween(3000)
            //spring(dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy) - I want this spec too
        }

    }, label = "rocket offset") { animated ->
        if (animated) Offset(200f, 0f) else Offset(200f, 500f)
    }

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rocket),
        contentDescription = "Rocket",
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .offset(rocketOffset.x.dp, rocketOffset.y.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: You want to use two `AnimationSpec`s at the same time? Or do you want to use them consecutively - meaning that you divide animation into two parts and use different `AnimationSpec` for each part?

Comment: @PrimožIvančič thanks for asking. I did and posted in my blog --> https://www.jetpackcompose.net/jetpack-compose-animations